# pdf of a function of a normal random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, partial-derivative, random-functions

Let $f$ be a function $f : x \mapsto y$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$; $m \geq n$.  $f$ is not invertible.  I have a random variable $X$ s.t. $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ where mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.  If it makes things easier, $\Sigma$ can be considered to be diagonal.

Is there an analytical way to calculate the probability (or log-likelihood) of $f(X)$?  What about its gradients with respect to $\mu$ and $\sigma$?  If not, is there a good way to estimate these?

EDIT: I'd be curious about the case where $f$ is invertible as well, as I may be able to tweak my problem, but it is suboptimal.

Comment: What is the relationship between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: There is none, $x$ is a placrholder variable as input to a function.  $X$ is a random variable.  I used $x$ since $X$ will be fed into $f$.

Comment: If the dimension of the range of $f$ is higher than the domain, say $x \mapsto (g(x), h(x))$, then the resulting support of the vector is actually still lies in a space with the same dimension as the domain - you cannot create a higher degree of randomness by doing this. This is a degeneracy. If you try to calculate the covariance matrix, it will be not have the full rank too. So it depends on what you want.

Comment: I think I agree with you, on the support of the output being in a space with the same dimension as the domain.  But I am not sure how that changes the problem.